# Date is less than specified date in Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a Jinja template where I want to display a message for users that were created before a specified date. I only have control over the template file. What are my options to accomplish something like the following.

```
{% if sub.start_date < datetime.datetime(2015,09,30) -%}
    Hello Early Members!
{% endif -%}
```

Obviously the code above does not work since datetime will not be recognized. So what are my options here?

Comment: dont they have a filter something like `{{"10-15-2015"|parsedate:"%m-%d-%Y" }}`

Comment: you could also use a javascript function and the javascript Date class

Comment: Doesn't look like they have a `parsedate` filter. I went ahead and toggled an element using javascript, but that's kinda hacky and it makes me feel dirty... I'm still wondering if there is a better solution out there.

Comment: there is always a better solution ... just change the view function to have a true false flag :P

Comment: Ask whoever controls the template invocation code to give you access. Or at least add what you need :-)